# Inset map in Print Composer in QGIS using irregular shapes

Tags: qgis, print-composer, inset-map

I have been trying, unsuccessfully, to create an inset map in the Print Composer (via the Add New Map button) but, instead of it having the shape of the viewport main canvas, I would like it to have the shape of, for example, a specific layer I am using in my project.

As can be read in the online documentation, the most common procedure is to resize the main QGIS window to the desired size and then, using Add New Map in the Print Composer, the new view will be displayed. This workaround has its limitations, as the main QGIS window cannot be freely resized: we are stuck if we want to display, for example, a vertical view -understood as the width being significantly smaller than the height- of a specific area of our map; the main window cannot be adapted to this shape, left alone if we want to display for some reason an L-shaped, a rounded or a triangular inset.

I know there's [this](https://north-road.com/2022/11/04/creating-circular-insets-and-other-fun-qgis-layout-tricks/) very useful trick here that basically allows you to clip your inset with the shape you want inside the Print Composer, but is there any way to do this directly, or something of this sort, from the main canvas?

Comment: What if in the Qgis map/canvas side you clip/mask your actual map background with your shape/polygon layer + also use this shape layer as an Atlas? You should be able to have a layout that both frames & clips the area you want to show somewhat automatically

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Kasper. It could be done, in fact, using Atlas features. However, I was wondering if there was any other more "native" way of achieving this.

I believe, for now, the only/easiest solution is to stick to clipping the inset with polygons.